# Кастомизация CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, ckeditor

Нужно сделать переключаемый цвет фона в CKEditor4, с зависимостью либо от класса в оболочке, либо от ивента клик на кнопку. Через css стилизовать не получается([image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Цвета: bg: #fff / #252931
color : #000 /  #989898

Comment: И как Вы пробовали изменить цвета с помощью CSS? Какие стили и для каких CSS-классов переназначали? Не так: `.cke_contents{ background-color:white; }`? [Документацию](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/features/colorbutton.html) смотрели?

Comment: @XelaNimed
Вот так обращался по css:
#cke_editor{
 background: #434A59 !important;
 body{
   background: #434A59 !important;
 }
}
Проблема в том, что библиотека обрисовывает дополнительный тег html, а в нем, само собой, свой body. Стили по итогу просто игнорируются. На просторах интернета нашел такой код:
 editor.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {
  this.document.$.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].style.backgroundColor = '#252931';
  this.document.$.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].style.color = '#989898';
  editor.focus();
 });
Но не могу привязать его к событию

Comment: Всё правильно - всё располагается в iframe. Либо используйте плагин, как показано в документации, либо переопределяйте стиль для body в iframe, например как показано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13959836/3129992).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением проблемы оказались эти 9 строк кода:

$('.theme_cont').click(function () {

```
if (body.classList.contains('_dark')) {
    editor.document.$.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
}
else {
    editor.document.$.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].style.backgroundColor = '#252931';
    editor.document.$.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].style.color = '#989898';
}
```

})